# ¿Cuál es la lógica para borrar/limpiar base de datos sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Debo de borrar los datos sqlite. 
No he podido encontrar una forma de borrar solo los datos (por completo), pero si el método para borrar la base de datos por completo.

```
Context.deleteDatabase(“nombre_tu_base_datos_a_borrar”);
```

Lo he probado y realmente funciona.

Este código lo he puesto al iniciar el primer activity. (en mi caso un iniciar sesión) para que después vuelva a crear la estructura correcta de mi bd

El detalle es que cada vez que el usuario cierra la app o cierra sesión. vuelve a ir a este activity y como entenderán el código de borrar base de datos se mantiene por lo que volverá a borrar, cosa que estoy intentando evitar.

**Ahí es donde necesito saber cuál es la mejor manera.** 
He logrado hasta el momento que lo haga una sola vez usando preferense

```
String m_identificadorBorrarBD = sharedPrefs.getString("m_identificadorBorrarBD", "0");

if(m_identificadorBorrarBD.equals("0")) {

        getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(“nombre_bd”);

    valoresGenerales.sharedPrefs.edit().putString("m_identificadorBorrarBD", "1").apply();
}
```

Hasta el momento funciona, pero como haría para que en otro momento deba de borrar la base de datos. El preference ya se encuentra en 1.

claro me diran que agregue el 1 en if de esta manera.

```
   String m_identificadorBorrarBD = sharedPrefs.getString("m_identificadorBorrarBD", "0");

if(m_identificadorBorrarBD.equals("0")  || m_identificadorBorrarBD.equals("1")) {

        getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(“nombre_bd”);

    valoresGenerales.sharedPrefs.edit().putString("m_identificadorBorrarBD", "2").apply();
}
```

la idea es correcta (porque funciona), pero cada vez que necesite borrar voy a tener que añadiendo mas valores en ese if y aumentando el valor.

¿Existe alguna mejor forma?

Comment: el user de tu app cambiará la opción para eliminar la BD?

Comment: no,  eso vendrá cada vez que se genere una actualización y sea necesaria borrar la data anterior.  por lo que se definirá por código

Comment: podrías guardar en un sharedpreferences la versión, y, si el sistema detecta que la versión que tiene el user es diferente a la guardada, cambia el valor de `m_identificadorBorrarBD` a 0, y así correría de nuevo tu código para borrar la BD.

Comment: claro podría.. pero en este caso cada vez que genere una version .. siempre borraría .. pero la idea es crear versiones y solo en algunas hacer el borrado

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Alternativa**

Cree un método antes de iniciar sesión que se ejecuta de manera manual (por el usuario)

**Al parecer, los admin no admiten esta respuesta como solución.**

entiendo que la lógica depende de la forma y visualización de cada desarrollador.

no pude encontrar alguna solución que me ayude por lo que opte hacerlo manual .

crear un botón que si el usuario presiona realiza la función de borrar datos.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, Por favor edita

Comment: No solo esta respuesta no explica nada, si no que en realidad no parece ser algo claro. En realidad, nunca deberias borrar la base de datos, si no actualizarla a la version que corresponda cada vez que actualizas tu aplicacion. Pobre del usuario que la use, si le vas a borrar todo lo que hizo cada vez que cambias algo.

Comment: En ocasiones si es necesario y la respuesta me ayudo, por eso lo pongo. gracias por su opinión, me ayudaría  en que se base en buscar alguna otra opción de solución ;)

Comment: por favor si aun no les parece la respuesta .  estoy dispuesto a eliminarlo. y dejar la pregunta abierta. saludos